# VBA Code to always copy the last row with selected cells only

Tags: excel, vba

I get stuck in selecting to always copy the last row with selected cells only (not the whole row). I tried to record a macro, but then it won't copy the last row with selected cells because the code is locating to particular cells.

I have column A-Z in sheet A, and I would like to copy column A:E, R:T, Y:Z, and only copy the last row for each time. Here is the code I have tried. Which part I can change?

```vb
Worksheets("A").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
Range("A16:E16,R16:T16,Y16:Z16").Select
Range("Y16").Activate
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("B").Activate
R = Worksheets("B").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("B").Range("A" & R + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
```

Comment: You must read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to `Select` anything. Just tell Excel what you are talking about. Instead of saying, *"about the worksheet I just selected"*, say *"about Worksheet("A")"*.

```
Sub TransferDataFromLastRow()

    Dim Rs      As Long             ' source row
    
    With Worksheets("A")
        Rs = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Application.Union(.Range(.Cells(Rs, "A"), .Cells(Rs, "E")), _
                          .Range(.Cells(Rs, "R"), .Cells(Rs, "T")), _
                          .Range(.Cells(Rs, "Y"), .Cells(Rs, "Z"))).Copy
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("B")
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Here's the narrative:-

1. "Talking about Worksheets("A"), take note of the last used row in the variable *Rs*. Then merge the 3 specified ranges into a *Union* and copy its value to the clipboard."
2. "Talking about Worksheets("B"), paste the contents of the clipboard to the range starting at the cell below the last used cell in column A."
3. "Clear the clipboard."

Note that a cell is defined by row and column - syntax `Cells([Row], [Column])` - where the column can be a number or the column's alphabetic ID. A range is defined by its first and last cells, like `Set MyRange = Range(Cells, 1, 1), Cells(15, 26))` = `Set MyRange = Range(Cells, 1, "A"), Cells(15, "Z"))`

Comment: Hi Variatus, the code that you suggested works really well. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try below sub-

```
Sub CopySpecificRange()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim lRowA As Long, lRowB As Long
Dim rngAE As String, rngRT As String, rngYZ As String

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("A")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("B")
    
        lRowA = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lRowB = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        rngAE = "A" & lRowA & ":E" & lRowA
        rngRT = "R" & lRowA & ":T" & lRowA
        rngYZ = "Y" & lRowA & ":Z" & lRowA
        
        ws1.Range(rngAE).Copy ws2.Cells(lRowB + 1, "A")
        ws1.Range(rngRT).Copy ws2.Cells(lRowB + 1, "R")
        ws1.Range(rngYZ).Copy ws2.Cells(lRowB + 1, "Y")
    
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Harun, Thanks for the suggestion. However, the above code will copy the whole row.

Comment: @kipper No. It will copy specific cells from last row.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That's my mistake, I accidentally didn't set  ws1 and ws2 to nothing